# Is there any way to limit resized image file size?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for a way to limit resized image file size.
Resized image size should not exceed given size i.e. 100KB.

This is my code to resize image:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Image_data))
{
    var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    var ratioX = (double)1800 / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)1500 / image.Height;

    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    var width = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var height = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    var newImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newImage);

    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    Image_data = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));
    string SmallImageData = string.Format(Convert.ToBase64String(Image_data));
    string subpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResizedImagePath"];
    bool pathexists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(subpath));
    if (!pathexists)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(subpath));
    }
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(subpath) + "/" + ImageName + ".jpeg";
    bmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

But above code generate image file of any size.

Comment: Generate a smaller or lower quality image in a loop until the result is under the desired file size.

Comment: See [how to set compression ratio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to adjust the compression. But this is just an arbitrary number, so you would need to do something like a binary search to find the largest value that result in an acceptable image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magick.NET provides an `Extent` parameter to specify a maximum file size output, which informs the compression. [Description](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/3b22c0436037cc3fdc11ff835675c7e55e9a6e21/src/Magick.NET/Formats/Jpeg/JpegWriteDefines.cs#L34):

> Gets or sets the compression quality that does not exceed the
> specified extent in kilobytes (jpeg:extent).

An example as a test case from the [source repo](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/3b22c0436037cc3fdc11ff835675c7e55e9a6e21/tests/Magick.NET.Tests/Formats/Jpeg/JpegWriteDefinesTests/TheExtentProperty.cs):

```
var defines = new JpegWriteDefines
{
    Extent = 10, // 10 KB target size
};

using (var image = new MagickImage(/* File */))
{
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Settings.SetDefines(defines);

        image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
        image.Write(memStream);
    }
}
```